# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'display_name' cannot be null?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It says that the 'display_name' cannot be null, but when I changed the     **$display_name = null;** **into $display_name = '';** the other field that I fill up will go to the database but in the display_name field it didn't saved. So can anyone help me to fix it ? thanks !

```
    <?php

class Users {

    public $display_name = null;
    public $email = null;
    public $password = null;
    public $salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";





public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
               if( isset( $data['email']) ) $this->email = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['email'] ) );
              if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
}

public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
              //store the parameters
              $this->__construct( $params );
}

public function userLogin() {
                   //success variable will be used to return if the login was successful or not.
                   $success = false;
                  try{
                     //create our pdo object
                     $con = new PDO( db_dsn, server_user, server_pass );
                     //set how pdo will handle errors
                     $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                     //this would be our query.
                     $sql = "SELECT * FROM gs_users_table WHERE email = :email AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
                      //prepare the statements
                     $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
                     //give value to named parameter :email
                     $stmt->bindValue( "email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                     //give value to named parameter :password
                     $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha512", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
                     $stmt->execute();

                     $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

                    if( $valid ) {
                          $success = true;
                     }

                     $con = null;
                     return $success;
                 }catch (PDOException $e) {
                      echo $e->getMessage();
                      return $success;
                 }
}

public function signup() {
     $correct = false;
     try {
              $con = new PDO( db_dsn, server_user, server_pass );
              $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
              $sql = "INSERT INTO gs_users_table (display_name, email, password) VALUES (:display_name, :email, :password)";
              $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
              $stmt->bindValue( "display_name", $this->display_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
              $stmt->bindValue( "email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
              $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha512", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
              $stmt->execute();
              return "Sign Up Successful <br/> <a href='login.php'>Login Now!</a>";
       }catch( PDOException $e ) {
                 return $e->getMessage();
       }
}
}


?>
```

Comment: What is the type of `display_name` in your database??

Comment: What are the complete attributes of display_name in the DB?

Comment: Please show us the definition for the table `gs_users_table`.

Comment: I assume `display_name` is defined as `NOT NULL` in your database table. This is why you get an error when you just have `$display_name = null`, it's not allowed. However, when you set it to an empty string, that is not the same as NULL (a special value to the DB). I also don't see you setting the variable anywhere in the code you posted above, which is why it probably remained null in the first case - add it to your constructor?

Comment: display_name is all so the name in my db

Comment: If display_name is not from the form and already in the DB, set `$this->display_name` in `userLogin()` after a successful login.

Comment: @ avip - When I put empty string instead of null, everytime I input on the display_name field, it doesn't save in my db. So I don't get it.

Comment: Apart from this problem, you may find this reading interesting: [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). In short, you should never connect in the every function, nor return a database error as a function result.

Comment: @japjap try hard coding it to another fixed value (not empty) and see if it saves? If it doesn't, please check the error logs, see if there's anything there, and also run `DESC gs_users_table` and update the question with the output.

Comment: @avip It saves, though it is only fixed. haha

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it sounds like the issue is that you're not setting `$this->display_name` so instead of:

```
$valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if( $valid ) {
    $success = true;
}
```

Try:

```
$valid = $stmt->fetchAll();

if( $valid ) {
    $success = true;
    $this->display_name = $valid[0]['display_name'];
}
```

Comment: You can do it with `fetchColumn()` too but you didn't post the table description so I don't know which integer to pass it.

Comment: what you want to know about the table ? I can give it to you.

Comment: Well, first, does the above code modification work? :)

Comment: no nothing happend, even if I change the $display_name = null or ''; .